# Pinescript - Convert Wells Wilders MA v2 to v4

Tags: pine-script

I have a function to calculate Well Wilders MA for v2.

It's used for calculate [DMI Stochastic Extreme](https://www.tradingview.com/script/410gUHI0-DMI-Stochastic-Extereme/)

```
wwma(l,p) =>
wwma = (nz(wwma[1]) * (l - 1) + p) / l
```

I'm going to convert it to v4

And I got error: Undeclared identifier 'wwma'.

Pinescript v4 doesn't allow recursive function.

Do you have any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using recursion in the v4, you first need to declare your `wwma` variable. In your case this would lead to:

```
wwma = 0. 
wwma := (nz(wwma[1]) * (l - 1) + p) / l
```

Here you declare `wwma` as a decimal by assigning `0.` as value.